# Call a function inside if condition in page_load?

Tags: c#

I have a If Condition in page load.Can i call a function inside if condition ?

```
if( //I need to call function here with parameters..)
        {
            messageOut = "invlid user";
        }
```

Function looks like this

```
public void CheckUserExistAndReporter(int Source,string messageIn)
{
   // Some code goes here
}
```

Here i  tried it out like below,Is that correct?

```
if(CheckUserExistAndReporter(int Source,string messageIn) )
    {
        messageOut = "invlid user";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that but that function should return a bool value.

Check this out

```
if(CheckUserExistAndReporter(someintegervalue, somestringvalue)
{
    messageOut = "invlid user";
}
```

Function looks like this

```
public bool CheckUserExistAndReporter(int Source,string messageIn)
{
   // Some code goes here
   return true; // or false depending on method.
}
```

`Here i tried it out like below,Is that correct?`

```
if(CheckUserExistAndReporter(int Source,string messageIn) )
{
    messageOut = "invlid user";
}
```

No this is not correct. When you make a call to a method you don't declare parameters, they are already declared in method declaration. In calling you only provide values for those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, like this

```
if(CheckUserExistAndReporter(Source,messageIn))
{
    messageOut = "invlid user";
}

public bool CheckUserExistAndReporter(int Source,string messageIn)
{
   // Some code goes here

   return true; // when user exists 

   return false; // when user does not exist
}
```